# Authenticating users in git with LDAP

Tags: windows, git, apache, active-directory

I have the following

1. Windows 20008 server as domain controller
2. Apache 2.2 installed and running
3. PHP

I installed GIT "Git-1.9.4-preview20140929" on apache and it works fine.
I need to make the user authenticate to GIT "push, pull, ...and so on  " using their domain credential (active directory)and give them the needed permissions who can read and who can read/write.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using something like [Bonobo Git Server](http://bonobogitserver.com/) that is [designed to work with AD authentication](http://bonobogitserver.com/features/#windows-authentication):

> - setup it with your IIS user management
> - Windows and Basic authentication modes support
> - use Active Directory with git to manage your access

Another option is [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/), which [supports LDAP authentication](http://gitblit.com/setup_authentication.html):

> Gitblit supports additional authentication mechanisms aside from it's internal one.
>
> - LDAP authentication
> - Windows authentication
> - PAM authentication
> - Htpasswd authentication
> - Redmine auhentication
> - Salesforce.com authentication
> - Servlet container authentication

Note that Gitblit's support for "Windows authentication" [isn't the same as AD authentication](http://gitblit.com/setup_authentication.html#H6):

> Windows authentication is based on the use of Waffle and JNA. It is known to work properly for authenticating against the local Windows machine, but it is unclear if it works properly with a domain controller and Active Directory.

Comment: I took a look at Gitblit, I'll try it but is there any way to make LDAP authentication by the git over Apache "the system I described"

Comment: @moh_sun, I'm sure it's possible, but it might not be easy. Why don't you want to use Bonobo? It seems like a good fit for your Windows / AD requirements.

Comment: I tried BONOBO, it works but there is some comments on it.1- it does not read the users from the active directory it give it manually (domainname/user).2- at using tortoise-git I can not commit on a folder changes, I only can commit by file. poor administration site of BONOBO